# Sending email using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Error received:  User-defined type not defined on 
Dim oapp As Outlook.Application

Desired result:  I have 2 tabs Sheet 1 and Email tab 
I wish to take a screenshot of cells B8 TO M108 and send it to my desired recipients in the email body 
I have the following code. I am not sure how to proceed. 
Could I lend some help?

```
Sub sendemail()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim oapp As Outlook.Application
Dim email As Outlook.MailItem

Set oapp = New Outlook.Application
Set email = oapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

email.To = Worksheets("Email").Range("A10").Value
email.CC = Worksheets("Email").Range("B10").Value
email.HTMLBody = 
email.Subject = "Snapshot"

email.Display True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late binding could help.

```vb
dim oapp as object, email as object

set oapp = createobject("outlook.application")
set email = oapp.createitem(0)
with email
    .To = Worksheets("Email").Range("A10").Value
    .CC = Worksheets("Email").Range("B10").Value
    .HTMLBody = ""
    .Subject = "Snapshot"
    .Display
End With

set oapp = Nothing
set email = Nothing
```

Comment: thanks pai cheng, how do i add the snapshot of range B8:M108 To my email body @PaichengWu

Comment: @user12151877 [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5049-pasting-an-excel-range-into-an-email-as-a-picture.html) could help

Answer (score 0):

In Tools/Preferences... 
add Microsoft Outlook ##.# Object Library.
Just check it.

##.# - Number of your office.
[image]

Comment: im unable to fo it

Comment: I don't understand. What does "unable" mean.